# Dicionário Python 3

Tags: python

Olá, alguém poderia me ajudar a entender porque 8 é a resposta correta? 
Desde já, muito obrigado. 
[image: Resposta 8 em anexo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função get(key, default) retorna o valor no mapa de acordo com a chave **key** específica.

No mapa temos as seguintes chaves: `1, 2, 3, 4`, sendo os respectivos valores os seguintes: `1, 1, 2, 3`

No exemplo:

```
fib.get(4, 0)
```

Vai recuperar o **valor** que possua a chave **4**, no caso, o valor **3**. Caso não existisse no mapa chave com esse valor seria retornado o valor **0**.

```
fib.get(7, 5)
```

Vai recuperar o **valor** que possua a chave **7**, como não possui nenhum valor no mapa com essa chave será retornado o valor padrão **5**

Como resultado então temos **3 + 5 = 8**

Uma referência didática: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm

Comment: Muito obrigado. Agora entendi perfeitamente. Vlw.

Comment: Fico feliz por saber que pude ajudar. Agradeço pelo aceite da resposta. Bons estudos!